# javascript, animation, opacity, range of values

Tags: javascript, animation, opacity

I have an animation working (basically) where a bit of text rises up the page.  I want the opacity to go from 0 to 1 for the first half, then from 1 to 0 for the second half.  I have the following js IF statement:

```
if (300 <= iCurPos <= 500)
{
    oFactor.style.opacity = (iStartPos - iCurPos) / 2 / 100;
}
else if (100 <= iCurPos <= 300)
{
    oFactor.style.opacity = (2 - (iStartPos - iCurPos) / 2 / 100);
}
```

One part or the other seems to work, but not both.  I can't figure out why.  If this kind of thing has been asked before, I apologize.  I don't know what search term to use.

Comment: well, for a start your if statements are broken

Comment: `300 <= iCurPos <= 500` should be `300 <= iCurPos && iCurPos <= 500`

Comment: I saw that construction in a question earlier today (I  had never seen it before--it's actually been a while); I don't know why I just assumed it would work; your fix did make my code work like I wanted (the text to fade in...then out); thanks!

Comment: Explanation: your code evaluates as `if((300<=iCurPos) <= 500)` which gives `if( true <= 500 )` or `if( false <= 500 )`, which is always going to be true. The `else if` will never be evaluated.